# Setting up basic chroot environment from a fedora ISO image in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, chroot, iso, disk-image

From a tutorial in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebootstrapChroot at TLDR section i was able to set up a chroot environment for 32 bit Ubuntu ISO image under 64 bit Ubuntu. Now i need to do the same with a fedora ISO image under Ubuntu but it gives me this error message:

```
Cannot mount /srv/chroot/Heisenbug_x64/remaster-iso/casper/filesystem.squashfs 
in /srv/chroot/Heisenbug_x64/remaster-root-mount, error=32
```

Obviously it is because such folder does not exist in fedora DVD but what is the proper way to do that?